# ¿Cómo funciona este código, arrays en java?

Tags: java, array

He hecho un ejercicio de clases y el código resultante, aunque funciona, no me queda claro qué hace.

No es que no sepa interpretarlo, sino que no entiendo cómo funciona internamente. Expongo el código y la duda.

> Realiza una función que reciba un array bidimensional de enteros y devuelva otro array bidimensional con loselementos copiados pero con el doble de columnas. Los elementos nuevos se rellenan con ceros. UtilizarcopyOf de la clase Arrays. Por ejemplo, si recibe {{1 , 2},{3, 4},{5, 6}}, devuelve {{1 , 2, 0, 0},{3, 4, 0, 0},{5, 6, 0, 0}}.

```
package arrays;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ejercicio6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // VARIABLES \\
        int[][] array = { {5, 8, 8}, {7, 4}, {8, 9, 7, 2} };

        int arrayTest[][];

        arrayTest = fillArray(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayTest));


    }

    /* Recibe un array y lo devuelve con el doble de valores. 
     * */
    public static int[][] fillArray(int[][] array) {

        // VARIABLES \\
        int result[][] = new int[array.length][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // Recorre la primera dimensión.
            result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length * 2);
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Ahora bien, mi duda viene en las siguientes líneas:

`int result[][] = new int[array.length][0];` Aquí estoy creando un array bidimensional de n x 0 dimensiones... Ni siquiera sé cómo eso funciona.

¿Qué estoy creando n direcciones de memoria que no apuntan a nada? ¿Que a puntan a un null? ¿Cómo es siquiera posible hacer que la segunda dimensión tenga una longitud de 0 elementos?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // Recorre la primera dimensión.
                result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length * 2);
            }
```

Aquí se supone que voy recorriendo la primera dimensión del array y que a cada dimensión le creo un array que es la copia de otro array pero con el doble de valores, llenando a los valores restantes... ¿Pero cómo es posible?

Supuestamente mi primera dimensión debería enlazar a arrays de una longitud de 0 elementos y al hacer eso, estoy ¿cargandome ese array? ¿y modificando la dirección de memoria?

Agradecería si alguien puede explicarme qué ocurre internamente; que funcione está bien, pero que no tenga ni idea de por qué, no lo está tanto, a mi parecer.

Gracias.

Comment: Me pareció muy interesante tu pregunta. Me gusta que seas curioso por las cosas. Te he dado mi respuesta y espero que te guste. Si tienes alguna duda, no olvides de comentarla. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes entender como funciona los arrays en Java. Cada array en realidad es un objeto, es decir, que internamente el objeto tendrá un [puntero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)) en la cual hará referencia a un bloque de memoria, donde estarán todos los elementos de dicho arreglo. El objeto también debería de tener otra dirección de memoria en la cual almacene la longitud del arreglo.

Por ejemplo:

```java
class Program
{
   public void main(String[] arg)
   {
       int[] elements = {1, 2, 3};
       System.out.println(elements.length);
   }
}
```

Esta línea de código:

```java
int[] elements = {1, 2, 3};
```

Es equivalente a esto:

```java
//el new int[] crea el objeto donde estará la referencia del array
int[] elements = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

Si te puedes dar cuenta, el identificador `elements` en realidad es un puntero implícito (digo "implícito" porque en java no existen los punteros, pero si internamente), en la cual, recibe la dirección base (del primer elemento) de un objeto y en dicho objeto, es donde estará el registro de memoria (el puntero) que almacenará la dirección base del bloque de memoria donde estén alojados los datos del arreglo.

Para entender esto mejor, lo plantearé en un diagrama de memoria:

```java
            Bloque A:     Bloque B     
elements -> |0x04|     -> |0x24|0x28|0x32| 
            |0x08|
```

Por defecto, la variable/puntero `elements` estaría apuntando a la dirección base del bloque `A` (es decir, a `0x04`).
El bloque `A` es el objeto creado a partir con `new int[]`, en la cual, tendrá dos direcciones de memoria. En la primera dirección (`0x04`) básicamente es el puntero, que almacenará la primera dirección de memoria del primer elemento del bloque `B` (es decir, la dirección `0x24`) y en la dirección `0x08` es donde se guardará la longitud del arreglo, que en este caso es `3`. El bloque `B` es básicamente donde estarán los datos del arreglo.

Entendiendo esto, es sencillo comprender como funciona los arrays bidimensional. Porque básicamente los arrays bidimensional también son objetos y que internamente el objeto, tendrá la referencia de un puntero en la cual apuntará a la dirección base de un [arreglo de punteros](http://decsai.ugr.es/~jfv/ed1/c/cdrom/cap8/cap810.htm), donde, cada puntero apuntará a un objeto de tipo `int[]`, donde dicho objeto, tendrá el puntero que hará referencia al primer elemento del arreglo.

Esta línea de código:

```java
int[][] array = { {5, 8, 8}, {7, 4}, {8, 9, 7, 2} };
```

Es equivalente a esto:

```java
int[][] array = new int[][]{ new int[]{5, 8, 8}, new int[]{7, 4}, new int[]{8, 9, 7, 2} };
```

Y aquí demostramos que en realidad estamos creando un objeto con `new int[][]` y después `3` objetos de tipo `int[]` en la cual, cada dirección base del objeto, estará almacenada en un arreglo de punteros (la referencia de este arreglo debería estar almacenada en el objeto creado a partir con `new int[][]`).

Para entenderlo mejor, lo plasmaré en un diagrama:

```java
Bloque A:          
 |0x04| -------
 |0x08|       |
            Bloque B:
              |0x24|   -> Bloque C: |0x64|0x72| 
                                       |
                                     Bloque F:
                                       |0x76|
                                       |0x80|
                                       |0x84|
              |0x28|   -> Bloque D: |0x80|0x84| 
                                       |
                                     Bloque G:
                                       |0x88|
                                       |0x92|
              |0x32|   -> Bloque E: |0x96|0x100| 
                                       |
                                     Bloque H:
                                       |0x104|
                                       |0x108|
                                       |0x112|
                                       |0x116|
```

Este diagrama, básicamente indica una representación de como estará registrado en memoria el array bidimensional.

**Explicación:**

El bloque `A` es el objeto creado a partir de `new int[][]`, donde la variable/puntero `array` (es el nombre que diste a la variable) apuntaría a la dirección base de dicho objeto, que en este caso es la dirección `0x04` y la dirección `0x08` es donde estará la longitud del array bidimensional, en este caso, sería `3` (porque es el número de filas).

La dirección `0x04` es un puntero en la cual almacenará la dirección base del bloque `B` (en este caso, es la dirección `0x24`). Luego el bloque `B` sería el bloque de memoria (un arreglo de punteros) donde estarán las direcciones bases de cada objeto de tipo `int[]`.

Esos objetos de tipo `int[]` son los bloques `C`, `D` y `E`. Entonces el bloque `C` es el objeto (de tipo `int[]`) donde estará almacenado el puntero (es decir, la dirección `0x64`) y la longitud del arreglo (la dirección `0x72`).

La dirección `0x64` es el registro que tendrá almacenada la primera dirección de memoria del primer elemento del bloque `F` (es decir, la dirección `0x76`). También recalco que los bloques `F`, `G` y `H` son los arrays donde están almacenados los datos de cada fila de la matriz. Este mismo análisis se lo puede aplicar para los demás bloques restantes (no lo explicaré porque sería muy redundante).

Entonces, cuando se entienda como funciona realmente un array bidimensional en **MEMORIA**, podríamos dar respuestas a estas preguntas:

> > int result[][] = new int[array.length][0]; Aquí estoy creando un array bidimensional de n x 0 dimensiones... Ni siquiera sé cómo eso funciona.

Ahí lo que estás creando es un objeto de tipo `int[][]`, que internamente habrá un puntero que hará referencia a la dirección base del arreglo de objetos (o arreglo de punteros), en la cual, almacenará la dirección base de cada objeto de tipo `int[]`, sin embargo, cada objeto (de tipo `int[]`) tendrá una longitud de `0` elementos.

Esto en memoria se lo representa así:

```java
Bloque A:          
 |0x04| -------
 |0x08|       |
            Bloque B:
              |0x24|   -> Bloque C: |0x64|0x72| 
              |0x28|   -> Bloque D: |0x80|0x84| 
              |0x32|   -> Bloque E: |0x96|0x100|
```

Si te das cuenta, es casi el mismo diagrama de arriba, la diferencia, es que los bloques `F`, `G` y `H` (representan los datos que tendrá cada fila de la matriz) nunca serán creados porque la longitud del vector es `0`. Por lo tanto, la dirección base `0x64` (del bloque `C`) no apuntaría a ningún dato del arreglo , debido a que, aún no se ha reservado memoria para eso.

Por ejemplo:

```java
array[0] = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

El código de arriba si crearía el bloque `F` en memoria y ahora el puntero (en nuestro ejemplo tendría la dirección `0x64`) si apuntaría hacia la dirección base de dicho bloque (que sería hacia el elemento `1` del vector).

> > ¿Qué estoy creando n direcciones de memoria que no apuntan a nada?

Mmmmmmmmm... No exactamente. Lo que se está creando es un arreglo de punteros en la cual apuntan a un objeto de tipo `int[]`, por lo tanto, si apuntan a algo.

> > ¿Apunta a un null?

No. Cada elemento del arreglo de punteros, apuntarán hacia la primera dirección de memoria de un objeto de tipo `int[]`, por lo tanto, no apuntan a `null`.

> > ¿Es posible que apunte a null si fuera el caso?

Si. Pero esto dependerá de como escribas el código de Java.

Por ejemplo:

```java
int result[][] = new int[array.length][];
```

Si no escribimos el `0` en el segundo corchete, se estaría creando un arreglo de punteros, donde cada elemento, apuntaría a `null`. Por lo tanto, al momento de obtener la longitud con este código:

```java
result[0].length
```

Nos daría una excepción (`NullPointerException`), debido a que, estarías accediendo a un atributo a través de un puntero que en realidad no apunta a una dirección de memoria perteneciente al programa, por ende, en este caso habría que tener mucho cuidado. Sin embargo, hacerlo de esta forma, evitas en asignar un objeto de tipo `int[]` en cada elemento del arreglo de punteros y esto ahorraría memoria.

Si le dejas en la segunda dimensión el `0`, si estarías creando un objeto de tipo `int[]` en cada puntero del arreglo de objetos y la verdad, lo veo de por gusto, debido a que, al momento que se ejecute el bucle, se estaría sobrescribiendo el contenido de cada elemento del arreglo de punteros. Así que las referencias de objetos que había anteriormente, se pierden y el recolector de basura sabrá en que momento libera la memoria.

> > ¿Cómo es siquiera posible hacer que la segunda dimensión tenga una longitud de 0 elementos?

Si es posible. Y tiene mucho sentido. Porque básicamente se crea el arreglo de punteros donde estarán las referencias de cada objeto de tipo `int[]`. Si nos fijamos en el diagrama anterior, lo único que se crea en memoria es:

- El objeto de tipo `int[][]`.
- El arreglo de punteros.
- Los objetos de tipo `int[]` en la cual, cada referencia estará almacenado en el respectivo arreglo de punteros.

En el mismo diagrama se explica todo.

> > Aquí se supone que voy recorriendo la primera dimensión del array y que a cada dimensión le creo un array que es la copia de otro array pero con el doble de valores, llenando a los valores restantes... ¿Pero cómo es posible?

Todo en esta vida es posible, menos que ella te ame. Nah mentira. Lo que hace ese código es simple:

En cada iteración va creando un objeto de tipo `int[]`, es decir, si nos fijamos en nuestro diagrama de memoria que habíamos hecho anteriormente, en realidad, se estaría creando en cada iteración, los bloques `F`, `G` y `H` que representan los datos del arreglo.

Básicamente el método [copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) lo que hace es crear un nuevo arreglo con la longitud que le pases. Es decir, si estamos en la primera iteración, entonces la longitud daría como resultado `3` y como se lo multiplica por `2`, `copyOf` nos retorna un arreglo de 6 elementos y como solo encuentra 3 datos, el resto por defecto son `0`.

Esto es como si hicieras esto:

```java
int[] element = new int[4];
```

Si imprimes en pantalla cada elemento del vector, dará como resultado `0`, debido a que, el recolector de basura al momento de reservar memoria, lo inicializa a `0` y esto es básicamente lo que pasa con el método `copyOf`.

> > Supuestamente mi primera dimensión debería enlazar a arrays de una longitud de 0 elementos y al hacer eso, estoy ¿cargandome ese array? ¿y modificando la dirección de memoria?

Mmmmmmmm... Si estás modificando el registro de memoria.

Al momento de hacer esto:

```java
result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length * 2);
```

Es como hicieras esto:

```java
result[i] = new int[]{5, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0};
```

Es decir, lo que está pasando en ese código es que se está creando un objeto de tipo `int[]`, en la cual, internamente, estará almacenada la referencia (la dirección base) del arreglo y a partir de eso, se puede acceder a cualquier elemento del vector.

> > Agradecería si alguien puede explicarme qué ocurre internamente

Con mucho gusto te lo explico, bueno, en realidad, ya te lo expliqué y quedé agotado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Veo que es algo larga, preparé una taza da café y me pondré a leerla hasta entenderlo todo, jajaja.

De nuevo, gracias!

Comment: @Manuel Te recomiendo leer el tema de [punteros y aritmética de punteros en C](https://www.infor.uva.es/~belar/Ampliacion/Practicas%20C/2.%20Punteros/Punteros_en_C_Transparencias.pdf). Yo sé que esto no tiene nada que ver con Java, pero si hablamos del funcionamiento interno, si sirve.

Comment: Gracias! Le echaré un vistazo!

Comment: MrDave1999 Acabo de leer la respuesta, un poco tarde, pero no tuve tiempo antes. Sinceramente, sublime. Mil gracias, me quedó todo bastante claro. También me leeré el enlace de punteros lo antes posible, es muy interesante el tema. De nuevo, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Los arrays son de un tamaño definido y no se puede modificar una vez creados. Por tanto, necesitas saber al crearlos su longitud total, pero en tu ejercicio no tienes esta información al inicio. Es más, para cada línea la longitud varía, así que en el mejor de los casos tendrías que crear N líneas de longitud M, donde M es la longitud de la línea más larga... no es muy eficiente si tienes 3 líneas de 4 elementos y una de 400.

Lo que hace tu código es crear inicialmente un array de N líneas de longitud 0, para ahorrar memoria y tiempo. Luego, a la hora de copiar cada línea, averigua su longitud y la crea, sustituyendo el array de 0 elementos por el definitivo.

Podrías hacer lo mismo así:

```
int result[][] = new int[array.length][]; //sin longitud, apuntando a null
```

La diferencia es que si intentas obtener `result[0].length` en algún momento, tendrías un `NullPointerException`, mientras que con la opción usada obtendrías un 0. En tu caso en particular, ya que nunca haces este tipo de comprobaciones, podrías ahorrarte el 0, que no aporta nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!